# is there a way to clone repository into subfolder of other repository

Tags: git

I have a git repository that have few sub folders, and i want to clone this repository as a sub-directory to another repository (locally) and be able to fetch, pull and track.

example:
from:

```
folder1
folder2
.git
```

into:

```
.git
folder
--folder1
--folder2
```

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for [`git-submodule`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules):

```
cd /path/to/other_project
git submodule add git@github.com/user/project.git folder
```

Comment: Im not sure this is what I need.
I just want the repository to be in a sub-folder, not with a different git management.

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways of doing such a thing:

1. `git submodule` - `git submodule` is a git repository inside any other git repository. You can either clone the whole repository or only part of it (Last X commits, specific branch etc)
2. `git subtree` - very similar to submodules but the main difference is where the data is stored.
3. Not exactly what you are asking but im putting here since its good to know it.
   See the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13738951/278405) and [manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree) for details.